# ActiveDirectory - LDAP query for objectCategory unexpected results

Tags: active-directory, ldap

AD is at 2003 functional level, some of our DC's are running Windows Server 2003, some are 2008, some are 2008 R2.

When using the following query:

```
(objectCategory=user)
```

I do not expect to see any result where the objectCategory attribute is equal to
'CN=Person,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=Contoso'

I expect only objects where the objectCategory attribute is equal to 
'CN=User,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=Contoso'

However, the query does indeed return all objects with the objectCategory attribute equal to
'CN=Person,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=Contoso'

My question then is this: Why do I see the search results that I do?  Does AD actively translate queries that include `(objectCategory=user)` to `(objectCategory=Person)`? I have looked at the schema definitions for both the Person and the User class, but I cannot see any reason for the query results as I am experiencing them.  I know that the User class is a subclass of the organizationalPerson class, which is a subclass of Person, but I can't see an attribute value that would explain this translation.

Comment: Can you clarify what objects you're expecting to see, and what you are seeing instead?  Having that `objectCategory` is not unexpected for a user account object.

Comment: This is not an answer to your question (hence the comment) but please stop using Windows Server 2003. Microsoft no longer offers security patches for it and as a result it is unsafe.

Comment: @user5870571, this was an over 7 year old question...  Are you going through all ancient questions that mention EOL'd systems and telling people that their systems are insecure?

Comment: @joseph alcorn I just respond to questions at the top of the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you get the person objects is because there us no such category as User.  User is a class.  By strict definition Objectcategory takes a DN attribute.  In order to avoid forcing coders to look up the schema DN, the query engine in AD allows you to provide a class and provides the defaultObjectCategory as the expansion.  So if you were too look up the schema of User you get this as the defaultobjectcategory:

```
CN=Person,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=jimbdom,DC=com
```

The proper expression to search for users is:
"(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person))".

Comment: Perfect explanation! Thanks much, that explains away all my confusion on this issue.

Answer (score -1):

User inherits from Person.  In other words, users are Persons.  The opposite is not true.

So if you search for user, you can also see persons.

From [Technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc773309%28v=ws.10%29.aspx):

[image]

Comment: I was also hoping that by poinintg out the documentation you might read through it to discover the issue in your answer.  The OP query is for a CATEGORY not a CLASS.